# Phonegap plugin, FacebookConnect for ios requires FacebookSDKResources.bundle but facebook sdk states it's no longer neded

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I was follwing the tutorial for the [Manual iOS Installation (Mac OS X)][1].

After I downloaded and installed the latest version of the [Facebook SDK for ios][2], everything was smooth up to third step of the tutorial:

```
4. Add the Facebook SDK for iOS resource bundle by dragging the 
   FacebookSDKResources.bundle file from the FacebookSDK.framework/Resources
   folder into the Frameworks section of your Project Navigator.
```

The problem is that the FacebookSDKResources.bundle file no longer exists and in it's place there is a FacebookSDKResources.bundle.readme file which states:

```
The FacebookSDKResources.bundle is no longer required in order to use the SDK
```

What can I do to make this step work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation surrounding this plugin seems to be out of date.

Indeed, that bundle no longer exists however I've found that just omitting it from my xcode project works fine. As long as the FacebookSDK.framework and the DeprecatedHeaders are included, everything should run smoothly! :)